# Better visualization of skipped stages in declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm looking into moving our scripted pipelines to declarative pipelines.

I'm using the when key word to skip stages

```
stage('test') {       
     // Only do anything if we are on the master branch
     when { branch 'master' }
     //...
}
```

This works, however the skipped stage is shown as green. I would prefer if it was shown as gray in the pipeline overview. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: at least in blue ocean a solution exists: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39628

Comment: There is also a ticket with a lesser scope (visualization) https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47286 but at time of this comment being posted, it is being sadly ignored.

Comment: This can possibly be done by using the [Simple Theme Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Simple+Theme+Plugin).

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your comment I suggest you to use [Jenkins Blue Ocean](https://jenkins.io/projects/blueocean/) when working with pipelines.

It provides a more modern and user friendly view for your pipeline projects. Even the pipeline itself is display in a much more convenient way.

Answer (score 1):

If the stage is appearing green for you then it's likely still actually running. A skipped stage [should look like this in the Jenkins classic stage view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXMnY.png). Consider the following code sample, which has three stages, the middle stage being skipped conditionally with the `when` directive.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Always run 1') {
            steps { echo "hello world" }
        }
        stage('Conditionally run') {
            when {
                expression { return false }
            }
            steps { echo "doesn't get printed" }
        }
        stage("Always run 2") {
            steps { echo "hello world again" }
        }
    }
}
```

This should produce the following line in your build log

```
Stage "Conditionally run" skipped due to when conditional
```

Another answerer of this question mentioned Blue Ocean, which definitely presents a beautiful presentation of the stage view. [Here is an image of how a skipped stage looks in the Blue Ocean stage view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gm6zB.png). Note that Blue Ocean is a UI and your job's underlying pipeline code will be the same regardless of which UI you choose to use.